# Angular formly - delete value hidden field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a angular formly, like here;
http://jsbin.com/fohiqahoxu/edit?js,output

On this moment if something is typed in the input 'firstInput' the checkbox appears (it's  not hidden anymore because 'firstInput' has a value).

When the checkbox is being checked the value of the checkbox is set to true. 
When the input in 'firstInput' is being deleted the checkbox is set to hidden BUT the value of the checkbox stays true. 
How can the value of the checkbox being set to null when it's hidden?

Thank you!

Here's the important part of the js file (copied from the jsbin from the link above):

```
function getFields() {
  // return your fields here
  return [
    {
      key: 'firstInput',
      type: 'input',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Input',
        placeholder: 'Formly is terrific!'
      },
      expressionProperties: {
        'templateOptions.label': 'model[options.key] || "Input"'
      }
    },
    {
      key: 'checkbox',
      type: 'checkbox',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Hidden box'
      },
      hideExpression: '!model.firstInput'
    }
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it by getting the checkbox element into a variable (any of the ways possible, like `document.getElementById`)
and than uncheck it by setting its state to false:
`checkboxElement.checked = false`

Comment: Thanks BUT I am looking for a more 'Angular-Formly-approach'. However this is may be a solution i'm hoping for a solution like a function inside the 'expressionProperties' or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution. Seems that is was just a part of the documentation... (lesson learned; read carefully and don't be impatient, if the question is not immediately answered; think (and read) again.

http://angular-formly.com/#/example/very-advanced/remove-property-on-hide

I will add more documentation in this answer later. The reason i don't delete my question is because maybe in the future people like me with the same question will come here in their search. And then they don't have to look further :)

Comment: this answer is out of date and the example code is incomplete